# Using an External monitor with my Laptop with a broken builtin screen

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

The builtin screen of my laptop recently stopped working. I connected an external monitor to my laptop and I received a signal. So it seems to be an issue with my built in laptop itself or the connection between my motherboard and screen. Unfortunately due to the current situation and the Official repair center being quite far way, I can't get my laptop checked out in the near future.

For the time being I am using my external monitor exclusively to get my work done. Is there any disadvantage to my laptop (extra strain for instance) in doing so for a long time? Additionally, would delaying fixing my screen cause bigger problems down the line (Due to a more significant hidden issue which caused my Laptop screen to not work)

Comment: I don't think there's any disadvantage in keep using it and such problems aren't typically of the kind that gets worse.

Comment: Very unlikely. In the past 10 or so years I've been using laptops it's been almost exclusively with external displays as I use laptop as a desktop replacement. None have gone worse for wear.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the confirmation. Haven't extensively used external monitors with my laptops before, and I have heard that it is more straining on the hardware. Looks like it won't be a huge issue for the next couple of months till i fix the screen.

Comment: We regularly use laptops with external monitors to provide a larger screen. You might go to display setting and turn off the internal display... but if all is working as you want, that's not required.